# exclude some data from a table SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to exclude the weekend and the holiday from my table:

[image]

for example in this picture I would like to exclude the date 19.01. and 10.01 from my table or it should show only 0 in 10.01.2016.

this is my code:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select intervaldate as Datum, tsystem.Name as Name, 
SUM(case when Name = 'Maschine 1' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine1,
Sum(case when Name = 'Maschine 2' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine2,
Sum(case when Name = 'Maschine 3' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine3,


from Count inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.id
    where IntervalDate BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
    and tsystem.Name in ('M101','M102','M103','M104','M105','M107','M109','M110', 'M111', 'M113', 'M114', 'M115') 
    group by intervaldate, tsystem.Name
    ) as s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is create a table in your database and store all weekend and holidays dates then use that table to filter your query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select intervaldate as Datum, tsystem.Name as Name, 
SUM(case when Name = 'Maschine 1' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine1,
Sum(case when Name = 'Maschine 2' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine2,
Sum(case when Name = 'Maschine 3' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine3,


from Count inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.id
    where IntervalDate BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
    and IntervalDate NOT IN (select WeekendOrHolidayDate from MyWeekendAndHolidayTable) 
    and tsystem.Name in ('M101','M102','M103','M104','M105','M107','M109','M110', 'M111', 'M113', 'M114', 'M115') 
    group by intervaldate, tsystem.Name
    ) as s
```

The below query will exclude weekdays only. There is no way to produce holidays from SQL if you want to exclude also holidays you have to store it somewhere in your database.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select intervaldate as Datum, tsystem.Name as Name, 
SUM(case when Name = 'Maschine 1' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine1,
Sum(case when Name = 'Maschine 2' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine2,
Sum(case when Name = 'Maschine 3' then Units else 0 end) as Maschine3,


from Count inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.id
where IntervalDate BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
and ((DATEPART(dw, IntervalDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
and tsystem.Name in ('M101','M102','M103','M104','M105','M107','M109','M110', 'M111', 'M113', 'M114', 'M115') 
    group by intervaldate, tsystem.Name
    ) as s
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For excluding weekend...you can use date function and IIF condition. If week number is 7 or 1 then  exclude in report...You can do this by right click on report properties and choose filter..

Answer (score 0):

Right click the row group in your tablix and select Row Visibility. In the Change display options, select Show or hide based on an expression. In the expression, this should work:

```
=iif(CDate(Fields!Date.Value).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday, true, iif(CDate(Fields!Date.Value).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday, true, false))
```

If there's a ton of data, for performance reasons I'd recommend trimming these rows on the database side.